# How to draw on View in iteration, as i had put the setNeedsDisplay method into infinite while loop

Tags: ios, uiview, setneedsdisplay

I am new to iOS, i have a problem with drawing on view in a loop,This is my drawRect method in class MyView.m:

`

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
     self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    x = rand() % (200 - 0) + 0;
    y = rand() % (200 - 0) + 0;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 160+x, 150+y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 160+x, 120+y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200+x, 200+y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200+x, 170+y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 250+x, 250+y);

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    NSLog(@"drawRect x: %d,%d",x,y);
  }
```

`

MyView is added into the ViewController as a subView in xib.

This my while loop in viewController.m:

```
    -(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    while (TRUE) {


        NSLog(@"while");
        NSThread* myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(reDraw)object:nil];
        [myThread start];
   // [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(reDraw) toTarget:self withObject:nil];        
        //[self performSelector:@selector(reDraw) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
        NSLog(@"after sleep");
          }
}


-(void)reDraw {
    [myView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

buttonClicked is the method which is called when i press the button to start while loop which iterate the setNeedsDisplay method, problem is that when i press the button everything comes stops working accept the drawing. button remains clicked and all other components come to a stop.

Comment: If you are new to iOS, why are you trying to use NSThread methods? That `buttonClicked:` method is hideous.

Answer (score 2):

When you press the button you go into an infinite loop on the main thread. The main thread is the one that does all the drawing. Drawing isn't done directly as a result of `setNeedsDisplay` though so all you're doing is queueing lots of requests to draw and then stopping the main thread so it never gets done.

Basically, you should never sleep the main thread, ever, for any reason, ever.

You should look at using an `NSTimer` to call your `reDraw` method as it will run at the rate you set and it won't block the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will try and let you know after that.